# cassandra: ~.cqlshrc does not work

Tags: windows, cassandra, config, cql

I am a new to use cassandra, and I want to config a cassandra.cqlshrc file then I can avoid having to pass credentials for every login using cqlsh. The codes in the cassandra.cqlshrc I wirted is this:

`[authentication]`

`username = cassandra`

`password = cassandra`

and I put the file into directory: apache-cassandra\bin
But it's not working, after I call the cqlsh in cmd.exe use command:python cqlsh
Note: I install the cassandra in windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: Actually there is no error. But after I start the cqlsh, and try to excute some commands, then cqlsh will notice me that I didn't log in. So, I think the cassandra.cqlshrc file is not working~

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`.cqlshrc` has to be in your user home directory.

That's the only supported location for now (tested with Cassandra 1.2.6). For Windows 7 that is `%USERPROFILE%\\.cqlshrc` (for example `C:\\Users\\<username>\\.cqlshrc` ).

You can create this file with copying `conf\\cqlshrc.sample` from your cassandra program directory to your user home directory and then start `cmd.exe` and run `cd %USERPROFILE%` and `ren cqlshrc.sample .cqlshrc`